# How to fix Deprecated issue in wordpress site for create_function?

Tags: error-handling

```
public static function registerWidget($widgetName){
    add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("'.$widgetName.'");'));
```

This is my code and the warning is:

> `"Deprecated: Function create_function() is deprecated in xxx.php" on 258 line`

How can I fix this?

Comment: I've also faced the same issue, theorically this should work:

add_action('widgets_init', function() { return register_widget($widgetName); });

But in my case it didn't. I hope someone can give us some light!

Answer (score 12):

You need to replace it with an anonymous function and the problem with the solution above is that the anonymous function doesn't have $widgetName in its scope.

Try:

```php
public static function registerWidget($widgetName){
    add_action('widgets_init', function () use ($widgetName) {
        return register_widget($widgetName);
    });
}
```

source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php